# Swiching window in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, htmlunit-driver

When I am using selenium on FirefoxDriver I am switching windows using the following code

```
final Set<String> allwindowID = driver.getWindowHandles();
        final Iterator<String> itr = allwindowID.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (parentID == itr.next()) {
                parentID = itr.next();
            }
            else {
                childID = itr.next();
            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(childID);
```

But the same code is not working when I am using HtmlUnitDriver. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: There is a fix mentioned in [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3914) thread. Try specifying windowname directly in `driver.switchTo().window(windowname);`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string references and not string values, use `equals()` instead of `==`.

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (parentID.equals(itr.next())) { 
        parentID = itr.next();   
    } else {
        childID = itr.next();
    }
}
driver.switchTo().window(childID);
```

For details: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Also you can re-write same method as

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (!parentID.equals(itr.next())) { 
        // No need to reassign same value to parentID  
        childID = itr.next();       
    }
}
driver.switchTo().window(childID);
```

Comment: Not working. Still getting the java.util.NoSuchElementException